# Name of an intentionally sharp, bright "bling" or "pring" sound on guitar?

Tags: guitar, technique, sound

For example at 3:31 in this video:

And at 0:48 in this video:

I want to know how to do that but I can't look it up because I don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joulin is correct. The *pinched harmonic* here is produced by touching the top string, which is unfretted,(making it also a *natural harmonic*) with the index fingertip, exactly above the 5th fretwire, and plucking with the thumb. It could just as easily been touched around the centre of the soundhole. That's because the harmonics split a string into even parts. Half way along gives an octave, a third gives the fifth of the root (would be B here), and the quarter - here - gives a second octave.

The open string natural harmonics don't need to be pinched, except here, he's holding down a chord, and that's the easiest way. But to produce good natural harmonics, touch with the fretting finger, and pluck close to the bridge. They come out more clearly that way.

It doesn't have to be an open string, either. Let's say you press the top string down on the 8th fret - C - and touched it over the 20th fret (8+12=20). there you get an octave pinched harmonic.

The second video is (natural) harmonics again, but this time, the top 4 strings, touched at the 12th fret with a straight finger, and strummed across. You can take the finger away - like a lot of people believe is necessary - or leave it there. In fact, you could touch the strings at that point again, with no effect! That's because they are not vibrating at that 12th fret; it's a node.

EDIT! - As Matt points out, another term for the first is harp harmonics. Harps are played using a finger and thumb, or two fingers, and pinched are played using the side of the thumb at the node, while picking the string, obviously very close to that node.The two are the same end product, with a subtle difference in execution, with harps perhaps being easier to hit the exact harmonic needed, due to being able to see the node more clearly - generally played over a fretwire, whereas pinched are rarely played anywhere apart from over the pups area. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Does it work on any guitar? Because I'm trying on a cheap electric 6 string (not amped because it's 4 am) and a garbage "classical" guitar. Can't manage it on either.

Comment: It works on every type of stringed instrument

Comment: I got it now. Took a few tries though.

Comment: On electrics, it's easier with some overdrive/distortion, which enhances the sound of the harmonics. Better wait till later...

Comment: Your answer isn't quite correct Tim, but better for you to update yours than for me to post another! In common parlance they're actually called "Harp Harmonics" rather than "Pinch harmonics". "Pinch" would more commonly be associated with a plectrum/thumb strike on an Electric guitar. You'll find a lot more references for Harp Harmonics in the manner of the first video if you search as such =)

Comment: Thanks. I can play natural(/harp?) harmonics now. I can't clearly play artificial/pinched harmonics or "squeallies" (likely due to my lack of pinching experience, low quality instruments, and cheap amp).

Answer (score 0):

The first one shows a **pinch Harmonic**. It is done with one hand, usually with you index finger resting on the string (but not fretting it) at a location that would produce a nice sounding harmonic (above fret 12,7 and 5 produce the clearest sounding harmonics) and then strumming the string with your thumb.

The second one sounds like it is just **natural harmonics**. You can play those by laying your finger on the string in the same manner as before (but here you can lay it over several strings at once) and strumming the strings in whatever way you choose.

Comment: I looked up pinch harmonics and now I have more questions than answers and am somewhat (extremely) frustrated...

Comment: @SebastianHahn they're not actually "pinch" harmonics - see my comment on the other more detailed answer.